# Java: Create and write in consecutive files

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I'm able correctly to create and to write into a new file, but don't in a second one or more.

What's wrong?

```
int numbOfFile = 0;

PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter("C:path\test" + numbOfFile + ".csv");

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : inSorting.entrySet()) {

    String key = entry.getKey();
    numbOfFile++;
    if (!(numbOfFile % 3 == 0)) {
        bw.println(key + " ");
    } else {
        bw.close();
        new PrintWriter(""C:path\test" + numbOfFile + ".csv"");
        bw.println(key + " ");
    }
}

bw.close();
```

Comment: In your "else" clause you don't assign "bw = new PrintWriter()"

Comment: in the else block assign bw= new PrintWriter(""C:path\test" + numbOfFile + ".csv"");

Comment: Thank you now it works!

Comment: I am astonished not to see `"C:\\path\\test" + ...`

Comment: @JoopEggen: this is the future!